# Get the position of a view on the screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin native (not forms) and I have an `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout`.
Is there any way to get the absolute position of the view relative to the screen and not relative to the parent?
I saw some solutions for this problem on `Xamarin.Forms` that loop through the parent view and add its coordinates relative to its parent, but it doesn't seem to work here.
I tried using `iv.GetX()` but this is for getting the position in relative to the parent.
What is the way to get the absolute position?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the absolute coordinates across the entire screen with the `GetLocationOnScreen` method.

like:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
iv.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

**Note**:

This value is calculated from the top of the screen, which includes the height of the notification bar.If those parameters are printed in the Activity's `OnCreate()` method, they are all `0`, and you won't get them until the UI controls are loaded.

It's better to get it in `OnWindowFocusChanged` method.

Comment: how does this work ?, can we get this in MAUI?